# Looping to find empty cells then copy above

Tags: vba, excel

I've found similarish results, but nothing that actually solves my problems, so forgive me if the start of this question seems familiar. I am trying to drop down a series of rows to find the first empty row - this bit i can do

```
Sub findblank()

Dim xrow As Integer, xcol As Integer
xrow = 1 xcol = 1

Do Until Cells(xrow, xcol).value = ""
      Cells(xrow, xcol).Select
      xrow = xrow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

It's the next step that has me stumped, short of using the dreaded sendkeys. I want to select all the rows of data above the blank cell, and copy them. I will then paste them into a new sheet and repeat this process for another area in the original sheet.

I will then go back to the original sheet with the last cell selected, reset xrow/xcol and continue down.

Essentially I am taking chunks of data, where there are large blanks inbetween, and copying them into a new sheet, where i want to put only one blank line between the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all the data is going into one sheet then why not delete extra blank rows?

Comment: Going with Sid on this one. If no modification to data is needed, then just deleting the blank rows in excess of one would be enough.

Comment: the data changes regularly, but i also need to keep it in its existing format if possible, as I have other less sophisticated peices of code searching for it and presenting it within the same sheet as it exists in basic form. There are 19 sheets, all with different data setups.

Comment: yes it shouldn't be a problem. The format won't change if you delete the extra blank rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (also, try to avoid relying on `Select` or `Activate` methods).

This approach defines a range object using the [Range object's `End` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx).  Since you are working with a contiguous range, this should be an option for you. Then define a worksheet variable for the destination of the `Copy` method, and voila:

```
Sub findblank()
Dim rng as Range
Dim destSheet as Worksheet
Dim xrow As Integer, xcol As Integer

For xcol = 1 to 10 '// This will let you run this loop on multiple columns
    xrow = 1 
    '// Define your contiguous range using the End property:
    Set rng = Range(Cells(xrow, xcol), Cells(xrow, xcol).End(xlDown))

    '// Define the destination for the copy/paste
    Set destSheet = Worksheets("Another worksheet")   '// Modify as needed

    '// Copy & paste to another worksheet
    rng.Copy destSheet.Range(Cells(1, xCol))

End Sub
```

Or, if you want to use a loop structure (although it doesn't seem necessary if you can just use the range `.End` method per above suggestion):

```
Sub findblank()
Dim rng as Range
Dim destSheet as Worksheet
Dim xrow As Integer, xcol As Integer
xrow = 1 
xcol = 1

'// Define the initial range
Set rng = Range(Cells(xrow, xcol))

'// Define the destination for the copy/paste
Set destSheet = Worksheets("Another worksheet")   '// Modify as needed

'// Loop until you find an empty cell
Do Until Cells(xrow + 1, xcol).value = ""
      xrow = xrow + 1
Loop

'// Once you exit the loop, just resize the rng object variable:
Set rng = rng.Resize(xrow, 1)

'// Copy & paste to another worksheet
rng.Copy destSheet.Range("A1")


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks David. I was trying to create in a loop because I have multiple columns, so it was to avoid repeating code with a column update each time :).

Comment: I think you will need a loop for that, but not this type of loop. The `Do / Loop` is inefficient here. Let me make a small update.

Comment: I made an update to the first suggestion to let you loop over multiple columns. Un-tested so leave a comment if it doesn't work or you need any more help with it.